# Laravel sorting last record

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm bulding a forum.

In the main page, I want to show the last reply for each forum.

The hierarchy is this:

**forums**

hasMany('App\Topic')

hasManyThrough('App\Topic', 'App\Repley')

**topics**

belongsTo('App\Forum')

hasMany('App\Reply')

**replies**

belongsTo('App\Topic')

I did this:

```
 $forum->replies()->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->first()
```

And it worked. But I want to sort by topics and replies.
If I post new topic after the last reply, I want that show as the last reply.

**Update**:
I did this, and it work. But is there any other way?

```
public function last() {
    $topic = $this->topics->sortByDesc('created_at')->first();
    $post = $this->replies->sortByDesc('created_at')->first();

    return ($topic->created_at > $post->created_at) ? $topic : $post;
}
```

Comment: What are the relationships for the forum, topics and replies?

Comment: get last replay, get last topic, check who is newer

Comment: the easy, eloquent way https://softonsofa.com/tweaking-eloquent-relations-how-to-get-latest-related-model/

Comment: @RossWilson I updeted the post with the relantionships.

Comment: "If I post new topic after the last reply, I want that show as the last reply". You want to show a topic as a reply? Try `union`.

Answer (score 1):

One solution I would suggest is to have the replied `touch` the topics.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

This way you can always order by the Topic's `updated_at` because whenever a reply is created/edited it will update the Topic as well.

To achieve this you would just need to add:

```
protected $touches = ['topic'];
```

The above is assuming that the method name for the topics relationship in the replies model is `topic()`.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should have relationships between all of this models. Than you can simply:

```
$forum->topics->replies->sortByDesc('created_at')->first();
```

Read more about available methods for collections: https://www.laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#available-methods

Comment: I think that he want this: he have replies and topic, and he want to show the one who is newer, so if there is a topic newer than replay show the topic, and if there is a replay newer than any other topics than show the replay

Comment: I think, that new topic at the beginning should have 1 post (main post what i assume is stored in reply table). If not, and your version is correct, than he have to use my above code, and similar to get the latest topic, and than compare themselves.

Comment: @AmirBar Yes, that excactly what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$forum->replies()->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write orignal table name in places of topics and replies in orderBy clause.

```
  $forum->topics->replies()->orderBy('topics.updated_at','DESC')->orderBy('repliese.updated_at','DESC')->first();
```

Comment: @yehuda4e do you have time stamps in reply table ?

Comment: @yehuda4e i have edited answer just try and see and if you again get error than attach a snapshot of that error let me see what error it is giving

Answer (score 0):

```
$latestReplay = Replay::orderBy('created_at','desc')->first(); 
$lastTopic = Topic::orderBy('created_at','desc')->first();

    if ($latestReplay->created_at->gt($lastTopic->created_at)) {
          echo $lastReplay->title." is the newer!!"; 
    } else { 
          echo $lastTopic->title." is the newer!";
    }
```