# Reducing amount of queries, page loading slow

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to minimize the amount of queries I'm using by "eager loading" a threads' replies pagination. But I'm a little unsure how to do it. Below is the code:

```
$unpinnedThreads = Thread::all()->sortByDesc(function($thread) {
                $replies = $thread->replies->sortByDesc('created_at');
        
                $lastTouchedPost = Carbon::minValue();
        
                if (!empty($replies->toArray())) {
                  $lastTouchedPost = $lastTouchedPost->max($replies->first()->created_at);
                }
                return $lastTouchedPost->max($thread->created_at);
              });
```

View:

```
@foreach($thread->replies->paginate(15)->setPath($thread->path())->getUrlRange(ceil($thread->replies->count()
                            / 15 - 2), ceil($thread->replies->count() / 15)) as $key => $pagination)
                            @if($key > 1)
                            <a href="{{ $pagination }}">{{ $key }}</a>
                            @endif
                            @endforeach
```

So far I have alot of queries in the debug bar that looks like this:

```
select * from `replies` where `replies`.`thread_id` = ? and `replies`.`thread_id` is not null
```

I was wondering how I could reduce the number of queries.

When I code: Thread::with('replies')->sortByDesc->, it throws calls to undefined method. However when I code ->with('replies'), it throws an error that says:

```
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::with does not exist.
```

Can anyone please help me?

Thank you.

Edit::

I've deduced the issue is in my method:

```
$unpinnedThreads = Thread::all()->sortByDesc(function($thread) {
                $replies = $thread->replies->sortByDesc('created_at');
        
                $lastTouchedPost = Carbon::minValue();
        
                if (!empty($replies->toArray())) {
                  $lastTouchedPost = $lastTouchedPost->max($replies->first()->created_at);
                }
                return $lastTouchedPost->max($thread->created_at);
              });
```

Does anyone know how I can optimize the method?

Answer (score 0):

Answer found here: [Laravel sorting last record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39143850/laravel-sorting-last-record)

"One solution I would suggest is to have the replied touch the topics. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#touching-parent-timestamps

This way you can always order by the Topic's updated_at because whenever a reply is created/edited it will update the Topic as well.

To achieve this you would just need to add:

protected $touches = ['topic'];
The above is assuming that the method name for the topics relationship in the replies model is topic().

Hope this helps!"

Answer (score 0):

That is really strange. It appears that you are calling `with()` in the model `Thread::with('replies')`, but the error is saying that you are calling it on a collection. The collection object does not have the `with()` method.

The bellow code should work:

```
$collection = Thread::with(['replies'])->get()->sortByDesc(function($thread)
{
    if (count($thread->replies))
    {
        return $thread->replies->sortBy('created_at')->last()->created_at;
    }
    else
    {
        return $thread->created_at;
    }
});
```

If you are not using the defaults, `created_at` must be configured:

```
protected $casts = [
    'created_at' => 'date',
]
```

Don't forget to create the relationship inside your `Thread` model:

```
public function replies()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Reply::class, 'thread_id', 'id');
}
```